# We are getting a white screen every time we come back to our React Native Expo App?

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, expo

We have built a webview app in React Native and we have published it to the app store. We are facing a major bug where if you use the app, then leave it for a significant amount of time and go back to it, it will just give you a blank white screen

Has anyone experienced this before or have a solution? Let me know if you need to see any more of our code

**Package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "------",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-error-boundary": "^1.1.12",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[image]

Comment: I’m having the same problem. Did you figure it out? Are you using the web view? My app also uses a web view.

Comment: The fix we did was monitoring when the app is in state. When the app is inactive or in the background, once they come back refresh the app.

  const { appStateVisible } = useAppState({ onReopen: handleLaunch });

Comment: Got it, thanks. I ended up finding my problem. It was a missing `await` in a background `healthKit:Workout:new` listener. Hard to debug when it only errors in the background!

Comment: Absolutely - I'm only using RN to load a webview, and it's taken a very long time to get to Production!